# How to access a variable defined out side into inside a class function

Tags: php, codeigniter

My code is

```
$var = md5(rand(1,6));
class Session{
  protected $git;
  public function __construct($config = array())
  {
     //// some code

  }
  public function _start_session()
  {
      //code again..
  }
}
```

I want to use the "`$var`" value inside class functions as globally.

please update me how to do this.

Comment: You can create a `method` that accepts your value, or create a second value for your `__construct($config=array(),$rand)`, or just another value in your `$config` `array`?

Answer (score 0):

functions outside any class are global an can be called from anywhere. The same with variables.. just remember to use the global for the variables.

```
$var = md5(rand(1,6));
class Session{
  protected $git;
  public function __construct($config = array())
  {
    global $var;
    //// some code`
  }
  public function _start_session()
  {
    //code again..
  }
}
```

Comment: public function __construct($config = array()) { global $var; log_message('ERROR',$var); } this not printing value

Answer (score 0):

define your $var as global and then use directly
like this..

```
<?php
function abc() {  }

$foo = 'bar';

class SomeClass {  
 public function tada(){
     global $foo;

     abc();
     echo 'foo and '.$foo;
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: public function __construct($config = array())
    {     
     global $var;          log_message('ERROR',$var); } this not printing  value.

Answer (score 0):

You can feel free to use variable, defined in global context (with keyword **global**).

But your example is not a good idea. When you want to change behavior or name of `$var`, you should rewrite all codes...

Try to use function `wrap` or even `static` class to `globalize` Your variable `$var`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dependency injection. where you pass the required variables to the constructor

```
$var = md5(rand(1,6));

$session = new Session($var);
$session->_start_session();

class Session{

   public function __construct($var, $config = array())
   {
       $this->var = $var;
   }
   public function _start_session()
   {
       echo $this->var;
      //code again..
   }
}
```